# What is metallic paper?

Tags: printing, paper

I am having a black and white digital landscape photo printed to frame and hang on the wall and one of the options on offer is 'metallic paper'. What is it and would it be appropriate in this instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is like normal paper, except that instead of just paper or plastic backing, it has a sheet of Mylar between the paper and the emulsion.

It is high gloss, and high contrast, abolutely ROCKS black and white prints. Really gives them a lot of depth when they have a good strong light source.

Comment: One tiny caveat, though -- they don't work well in a dark environment with accent lighting, since they rely on diffuse lighting from the environment to provide the "white". When they're displayed properly, they are spectacular -- almost like a daguerreotype -- but there are some locations where they just won't work (also like a daguerreotype), and something a little more like a ferrotype (not the emulsion-on-iron version, I mean the *glossy print dried face-down on a polished surface* effect) would be more appropriate for increasing contrast.

Comment: Another caveat is that putting the metal prints behind glass cuts down on some of the gloss of the image.

Comment: Great point about the strong light source @Stan, I forget that folks a lot of times display images in weak light. @Brad, yeah, but you have that problem with standard glossy images too... part of why I hate putting prints behind glass if I don't have to.